# Add user that can modify db, but not delete it

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

SQL Server: add user that can modify database, but not delete it.

I create user, add role db_owner to Securables for my database.

And I use:

```
USE master
DENY DROP TO [user];
GO
```

to stop that user from deleting the database.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: A `USER` with the `db_owner` role can do *almost* anything to a database, including `DROP` it; perhaps the `USER` shouldn't have the `db_owner` role and should have a different one, such as `db_ddladmin`? But why do you want someone to be able to modify the `master` database? Generally you shouldn't be doing anything in that database.

Comment: Thank you, it's work!